# Filter core data items based on search text

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data, filter

I am trying to filter items based on text (mySearchText) from a search bar. So far I have got:

```
items = try context.fetch(Item.fetchRequest())
filtered data = items.filter { ($0.myArray?.contains(mySearchText))!}
```

This works if I enter the full text e.g. if I enter "Hello" into the search bar it will filter items with Hello in myArray.

However if I just enter "Hel" it won't filter the same item. How can I filter the items even if only a partial search term is used?

I want filteredData to be the items that have an array containing the string so

```
var filteredData: [Item] = []
```

e.g. if

item 1.myArray = ["cat", "dog", "monkey"] and

item 2.myArray = ["horse", "zebra", "cow"]

mySearchText = "o"

I would like filteredData to be item1 and item2 (cow in item 1 and dog in item 2 both contain "o")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling *contains()* on an array which means you're not doing string matching but instead looking for objects equal to your mySearchText object, so your looking for objects equals to "Hello" or "Hel" in that array.

To do string matching instead you need to filter one level down so to speak. Here is my version where I assume myArray is an array of strings

```
items = try context.fetch(Item.fetchRequest())
var filteredData = [Item]()
for item in items {
   if item.myArray?.filter({$0.contains(mySearchText)}).count > 0 {
     filteredData.append(item)
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clearer in the question. I want filteredData to be the items that have an array containing the string so

    var filteredData: [Item] = []

Updated the question now

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect this. (I did it on my phone so excuse me for any syntax or formatting mistakes)

Answer (score 0):

Its work fine when i use the code below, maybe you should use string to filter based on it.

```
    var mySearchText = "a"
    var items = ["Adam", "Ahmad", "abdalla", "abcd", "efj", "hijk"]
    let filtereddata = items.filter { ($0.lowercased().contains(mySearchText))}

    print(filtereddata.count)  // 4
```